Don't render component until shown, but then don't destroy when hidden
I have a tabbed interface and I don't want the component on the 2nd tab to render until the 2nd tab is selected.
However, I don't want the component to be destroyed (only hidden) when the 1st tab is selected.
v-show will cause the component to be rendered as soon as the page opens and not wait until the tab is selected.
v-if will cause the component to be rendered at the correct point, but will then destroy and recreate it as the user navigates back and forth.
The reason I want this functionality is that I have a 3rd party component that gets the height of its parent on first render and sizes itself to fit. If it's rendered while on a hidden tab, the parent doesn't have any height and so it looks wrong when it's shown. If I use the v-if technique, it displays correctly, but it loses state, e.g. scroll position, each time the user navigates away from it.
The same component works perfectly on the 1st tab as it gets the height on first render and then is just hidden and shown as needed.
I'm relatively new to vue so not sure if this is possible. I vaguely remember having something like this in react a couple of years ago where it wouldn't render the component until it was first shown, essentially a deferred render.

The question is too broad, it's not constructive to discuss something in principle when it's specific to your code. You can either store all state including scroll in parent or global state, or use KeepAlive to prevent an  instance from being destroyed. You probably asked about the latter

Consider using a boolean for each page that is triggered once upon clicking the tab, triggering a v-if.
import { ref } from 'vue';
tab1Loaded = ref(false);
currentTab = ref(0);
...
<button @click="tab1Loaded = true; currentTab = 1;"></button>
<template v-if="tab1Loaded">
    <tab1 v-show="currentTab === 1"></tab1>
</template>


Simple and effective. I actually thought of something very similar last night in bed using a watch (I have some very boring dreams ), but this is simpler.

If you are using Vue 3, you can try v-lazy-show of Antfu - Member of Vuejs core team.

It can be helpful to use with some component that is expensive to create/mount. For example, if you have a tabs component, that some tab contains a heavy component. Using v-if, it will get the component destroyed and re-created when switching tabs. Using v-show, you will need to pay the mounting cost on the initial render even you haven't switch to that tab yet.
With v-lazy-show, you can have the best of both worlds. You can think it as a v-show that lazy initializes, or a v-if that caches the DOM.


This looks like exactly what I want; however, my company is very conservative about adding 3rd party libraries / components so would be tricky to actually use this here. I will see if we can use this in the future.
